# Making Username Case-insensitive in Glassfish JDBC-Realm

Tags: oracle11g, glassfish-3, jdbcrealm

We have a Glassfish JDBC-Realm which uses an Oracle11g database for authentication. The username field is case sensitive, is there a way to make the username authentication case insensitive?

Comment: You can try to turn off case sensitivity in Oracle DB:
ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE;

Comment: Do you mean turning off the case sensitivity for the entire database? Because in that case it wont be a feasible solution; changing the case sensitivity for the whole database (or even the table) is not possible, because for instance there is a PASSWORD column in the very same table, which should obviously remain case-sensitive.

Comment: No, I mean to turn of case sensitivity just for role, witch is used by Glassfish. ALTER SYSTEM SET SEC_CASE_SENSITIVE_LOGON = FALSE; will not turn off case sensitivity for all DB.